# Moles is not working with MVC3 (System.Web.Mvc.dll)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, moles

I just started investigate moles framework and I get not really good experince from start.
By some reason I can't  generate moles for the System.Web.Mvc.dll (v.3)

I will try to explain my problem step-by-step

1. In just created empty solution I adding two project's (Asp.Net MVC 3 and Test).
2. Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\System.Web.Mvc.dll) reference  in test project.
3. Add Moles Assemly (in VS2010) for System.Web.Mvc.dll in my test project.
4. Build project.

In step 4 I get a following error

```
    ------ Build started: Project: SampleMvcApplication.UnitTests, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  Microsoft Moles v0.94.51023.0 - http://research.microsoft.com/moles - .NET v4.0.30319
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.

  00:00:00.00> moles
    Moles : info : metadata : ignoring reference D:\Samples\Moles\SampleMVC\SampleMvcApplication\SampleMvcApplication.UnitTests\MolesAssemblies\System.Behaviors.dll
    Moles : info : metadata : ignoring reference D:\Samples\Moles\SampleMVC\SampleMvcApplication\SampleMvcApplication.UnitTests\MolesAssemblies\System.Moles.dll
    Moles : info : metadata : ignoring reference D:\Samples\Moles\SampleMVC\SampleMvcApplication\SampleMvcApplication.UnitTests\MolesAssemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Moles.dll
    Moles : info : configuration : diagnostic is on
    Moles : info : metadata : loading C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll
    Moles : info : compilation : output assembly name: System.Web.Mvc.Moles
Moles : warning : metadata : failed to load module System.Web.Mvc.dll:
Moles : warning : metadata : Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
Moles : warning : metadata : Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
Moles : error : code : assembly contains no types or failed to load properly
  00:00:00.20> moles generator 1 errors, 3 warnings
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Moles\bin\Microsoft.Moles.targets(79,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @D:\Samples\Moles\SampleMVC\SampleMvcApplication\SampleMvcApplication.UnitTests\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args" exited with code -1005.
------ Build started: Project: SampleMvcApplication, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  Microsoft Moles v0.94.51023.0 - http://research.microsoft.com/moles - .NET v4.0.30319
  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.

  00:00:00.00> moles
    Moles : info : metadata : loading C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.dll
    Moles : info : compilation : output assembly name: System.Web.WebPages.Moles
    Moles : info : code : found 71 types
    Moles : info : code : visibility: exported or assembly(System.Web.WebPages.Moles)
    00:00:00.34> code generation
      Moles : info : code : generating code at D:\Samples\Moles\SampleMVC\SampleMvcApplication\SampleMvcApplication\obj\Debug\Moles\swwp\m.g.cs
      00:00:00.46> stubs generation
        Moles : info : code : generated 23 stub types
      00:00:00.86> moles generation
        Moles : info : code : generated 33 mole types
    00:00:01.70> compiling
      Moles : info : compilation : Moles assembly: D:\Samples\Moles\SampleMVC\SampleMvcApplication\SampleMvcApplication\MolesAssemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Moles.dll
  00:00:02.43> moles generator 0 errors, 0 warnings
  SampleMvcApplication -> D:\Samples\Moles\SampleMVC\SampleMvcApplication\SampleMvcApplication\bin\SampleMvcApplication.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I investigated all topics that I found but nothing helps ( I even did't found some good answer and explanation about this problem.)

This not helps too (solution excluding problematic types)
[Cannot use moles to mock the MVC framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620487/cannot-use-moles-to-mock-the-mvc-framework)

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: I get the same issue, my guess is that there is a bug in Pex when used against MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using unit tests? If yes, check that you have MVC 3 dll reference in your unit tests.

Comment: nope. I'm use mstests. Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework And I added MVC 3 dll to test project

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to add a reference to the moles framework directly. After creating your test project and adding a reference to the project you're testing, right click on that reference and select Add Moles Assembly. This should create a .moles file in the root of your test project. Now build your test project and you're good to go!